# Reading and writing to hadoop sequence file using scala

Tags: hadoop, scalding

I just started using scalding and trying to find examples of reading a text file and writing to a hadoop sequence file. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `com.twitter.scalding.WritableSequenceFile` (please note that you have to use the fully quantified name, otherwise it picks up the cascading one). Hope this helps.